# How can I assign a list (or series) to every element in column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I assign temp_list to every element in the column "PLAYERS"?

```
temp_list =['a','b']

    DATE         COUNTRY  COUNTRY_ID  COUNT  PLAYERS
0   1980   United States         840     42        0
1   1980  Czech Republic         203      2        0
2   1980     New Zealand         554      3        0
3   1980           Italy         380      4        0
4   1980        Paraguay         600      2        0
5   1980          Brazil          76      3        0
6   1980           Chile         152      2        0
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a list of lists with length same of dataframe and assign it?

```
In [685]: df['PLAYERS'] = [temp_list] * len(df.index)

In [686]: df
Out[686]:
   DATE         COUNTRY  COUNTRY_ID  COUNT PLAYERS
0  1980   United States         840     42  [a, b]
1  1980  Czech Republic         203      2  [a, b]
2  1980     New Zealand         554      3  [a, b]
3  1980           Italy         380      4  [a, b]
4  1980        Paraguay         600      2  [a, b]
5  1980          Brazil          76      3  [a, b]
6  1980           Chile         152      2  [a, b]
```